# Add buttons dynamicaly in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

want to add  buttons dynamically. I tried like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){ 

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
    Button newText = new Button(getActivity());
    newText.setText("This is a fragment");
    newText.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    return view;
}
```

Comment: create a liner layout in yout home.xml and add view as given in below answer.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your View you can add a layout then add your button inside the layout,
like so:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layoutContainer);
layout.addView(newText);
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/layoutContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#006699"
    >
</LinearLayout>